# Logic in Prolog

Tags: prolog

So, I was writing the code for removal function (remove the Val from the list and return new one) on prolog and at first I wrote this:

```
removal([], _, []).
removal([Val|T], Val, Y) :- removal(T, Val, Y).
removal([H | T], Val, Y) :- removal(T, Val, [Y, H]).
```

Which makes sense to me:

1. If the lists are empty, stop
2. If the head of the list is equal to the value, then skip it
3. If the head of the list is not equal to the value, then add it to the end of the Y list, and continue without it.

However I kept getting errors until I changed it to this:

```
removal([], _, []).
removal([Val|T], Val, Y) :- removal(T, Val, Y).
removal([H | T], Val, [H | Y]) :- removal(T, Val, Y).
```

It's almost the same, except for two things in 3rd step:
We add H in the front of list Y, even though (I think) it should be added at the end;
It seems that we add it in lhs, but for me it feels a counter-intuitive, since I thought we check values on the lhs, like in second step we check whether H == Val, so it's as if we are checking whether both lists X and Y start with the same value.

Could you please explain me why it is the way it is?

Comment: You7 do not add it to the end of the list. You only make a recursive call with `[Y, H]` as third parameter. Eventually it will aim to evaluate the base case `removal([], _, [])`, but unfication with the empty list will thus fail.

Comment: It's curious how a language that's supposed to be declarative and  easier for humans to program is actually counter-intuitive to them even in the simplest of cases.

Comment: @MaxB It's because the direction of data flow is not explicit. In functional languages you know exactly what "comes out". Here, not so much. You just have a constraint among several values. Plus, coming from other languages you are practically hardcoded to look for LHS and RHS.

Comment: Not sure whether [my notes on list processing](https://github.com/dtonhofer/prolog_notes/tree/master/other_notes/about_list_processing) will help here. Sometimes they are hard to understand.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer Yes, I'd love to see some psychological experiments on people with no programming experience whatsoever: Which is easier: pure Prolog or pure Erlang (or something)

Comment: @MaxB This summer I read [Syntonicity and the psychology of programming](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/232062764_Syntonicity_and_the_psychology_of_programming) which concludes that Prolog is "hard" because it doesn't readily allow to take the "homunculus" stance of a daemon going through the list of instructions, and that the "Byrd Box" model does not help _According to the main hypothesis, then, the choice-point model (where people are encouraged to identify with one thing, Prolog) should be easier to teach than the Byrd box model (where people are encouraged to identify with ..._

Comment: _each procedure call separately). This effect will be magnified when a syntonic metaphor is used in the teaching process. Sure enough, Mulholland has found that choice-point models do help to make it easier to understand Prolog execution traces._

Comment: @DavidTonhofer So people have done this experiment (Prolog vs functional)? Was one of them easier?

Comment: @MaxB No, I don't think anyone has made an experiment along those lines yet.